# MySQL Time between two columns

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table setup to track energy usage and my table consists of 3 columns:

| Consumption | interval_start | interval_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.079 | 2023-06-10 00:00:00 | 2023-06-10 00:30:00 |
| 0.025 | 2023-06-10 00:30:00 | 2023-06-10 01:00:00 |
| 1.250 | 2023-06-10 01:00:00 | 2023-06-10 00:30:00 |
| 3.524 | 2023-06-10 01:30:00 | 2023-06-10 02:00:00 |
| 3.269 | 2023-06-10 02:00:00 | 2023-06-10 02:30:00 |
| 3.211 | 2023-06-10 02:30:00 | 2023-06-10 03:00:00 |

The start and end columns are both datetime and consist of 30 min slots.

I have the first part of the statement already where I select add up the value of consumption:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(consumption), 3) AS c 
FROM electricity 
WHERE
```

but don't understand how I can do the second part.

I need to select all consumption values between a start and end datetime.

eg. where interval_start is 2023-06-10 00:00:00 AND interval_end is 2023-06-10 02:30:00 and everything in between this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intervals are entirely contained within your time window, then this should give what you need:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(consumption), 3) AS c
FROM electricity
WHERE interval_start BETWEEN "2023-06-10 00:00:00" AND "2023-06-10 02:30:00"
AND interval_end BETWEEN "2023-06-10 00:00:00" AND "2023-06-10 02:30:00"
```

However, if you have intervals that straddle the boundary (ie started before 2023-06-10 00:00:00 but finished after) then that becomes more complex and you would need to clarify the logic that should be used.

Comment: Thank you. The intervals are every 30 mins so this should work.